# Solving the Pulley Problem for the radius of one of the pulleys

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I've been working on a project involving some pulleys, and while trying to work out some of the math I was happy to find it's already a mathematical problem!

[image: The Pulley Problem] with the solution given as [image: Solution]
([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_problem?wprov=sfla1))

The result of this equation gives the length of the required belt, but since my project doesn't involve custom belts (but rather what I can pick up from the hardware store), I'd much prefer to have this solved for $r_2$.

Solving for $r_2$ is trivial, except for its presence in the definition of $\theta$. That's where I got stuck. I also tried plugging it into wolfram alpha, and playing around with treating the trig functions in their complex exponential form, and that's precisely when I decided to reach out for help haha.

Note: In the end, I'm also hoping to treat $P$ as $P=r_1 + r_2 + d$, where $d$ is the clearance between the pulleys. This is a more useful metric for me, as I can assign a constraint that, say, $d>1in.$, but that further complicates solving for $r_2$ so I refrained from including that in the initial question.

Comment: You need to find $r_2$. What is known?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I know $r_1$, the length of the belt (not shown, but call it $L$), and if we allow $P=r_1 + r_2 + D$, I know $D$ as well. I believe I know every variable but $r_2$, but I've been told there's no analytic solution to solve for $r_2$ because of its presence in the definition of theta

Comment: It's because equation for $r_2$ is transcendental. But I believe you don't need analytical solution, only method for computing $r_2$ with necessary accuracy for given $D$, $r_1$ and $L$. Is it correct?

Comment: Equation for $r_2$ looks like $$2\sqrt{4r_1r_2+2D(r_1+r_2)+D^2}+2\pi r_1-2(r_1-r_2)\arccos\frac{r_1-r_2}{r_1+r_2+D}-L=0$$ This equation can be solved by numerical methods or by plotting left-hand side for $x=r_2$ and finding intersection with x-axis.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu perfect, thank you! This will make programming the solution much easier. I've always been a fan of Newton's method for finding 0s, would that be appropriate here?

Comment: Looks like that. Plot for $r_1=3$, $D=2$, $L=24$ looks only slightly non-linear for $r_2\in[0;r_1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as
$$\cos\frac\theta2= \frac{r_1-r_2}{r_1+r_2+d}$$
and then solve for $r_2$
$$r_2=\frac{r_1(1-\cos\frac\theta2)+d\cos\frac\theta2}{1+\cos\frac\theta2}
$$
which can be further simplified to
$$r_2 =\frac d2+(r_1-\frac d2\tan^2\frac\theta4)
$$

Comment: So if I use that r2 term in the initial equation (which I'm trying to solve in terms of r2), the r2 terms go away and I'm left with thetas. I may have explained my question poorly, or I'm misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: @JShoe - I do not understand. I assume that you intent to solve for $r_2$ in terms of $\theta$

Comment: The equation I want to solve is the first one, although it's not listed as an equation because wikipedia left off the equals sign, and a variable to represent the length. Sorry, I'm on mobile and didn't mean to end the comment, one moment here.

Comment: L = 2Psin(theta/2) + r1(2pi - theta) + r2(theta) is the equation I'm trying to solve for r2. My problem is that theta is also dependant on r2, so I need to deal with that, and I'm not sure how.

Comment: @JShoe - then,  there is no analytic solution

Comment: Well, good to know so I don't have to keep following this rabbit hole! Can you tell me any more about why?

Comment: @JShoe - simply because you have both $\sin \theta $ and $\theta$